# Shrinking a stack in personal implementation crashes when using realloc

Tags: c, stack, realloc

I am experiencing a problem in shrinking the size of a stack in a personal implementation of the data structure.

I suppose is due to bad usage of `realloc()`. When the execution comes it (`spop()`, `empty()`) (If I remove the `realloc` and decrement the number of elements, the implementation works fine), the program just ends (crash).

What would be a better way to use the function in my implementation, or what might the problem be?

**stack.h**

```
/*Stack.h*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>


typedef struct Stack{   
    char **storage;     //Elements container;
    size_t capacity;    //Total amount of elements POSSIBLE in the stack;
    size_t size;        //Total amount of elements within the stack;
}Stack;

Stack *salloc(size_t);
void spush(Stack *, char *);
char *spop(Stack *);
void speek(Stack *);
void empty(Stack *);
void print_stack(Stack *);  //Useful but non-conventional
```

**stack.c**

```
/*Stack.c*/
#include "stack.h"

Stack *salloc(size_t size){
    Stack *s = (Stack *)malloc(sizeof(s));
    s->storage = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * size);
    s->capacity = size;
    s->size = 0;
}

static int expand_stack(Stack *s){
    s->storage = realloc(s->storage, (s->capacity * 2));
}

static void shrink_stack(Stack *s){
    s->storage = realloc(s->storage, (s->capacity / sizeof(char *)));
}

void spush(Stack *s, char *elem){
    char *p = elem;
    int k = (s->capacity-1) - s->size; //Next free position

    if(s->size == s->capacity)
        expand_stack(s);

    s->storage[k] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(p) + 1));
    memcpy(s->storage[k], p, (strlen(p) + 1));
    // *(s->storage[k] + (strlen(p) + 1)) = '\0';
    s->size++;
}

char *spop(Stack *s){
    int k = s->capacity - s->size;

    if(s->size == 0)
        return NULL;

    free(s->storage[k]);
    s->size--;
    shrink_stack(s);
}

void speek(Stack *s){
    int k = s->capacity - s->size;
    printf("'%s'\n", s->storage[k]);
}

void empty(Stack *s){
    s->storage = realloc(s->storage, 0);
    s->capacity = 0;
    s->size = 0;
}

void print_stack(Stack *s){
    printf("[STACK] = {\n");
    int k = s->capacity - s->size;
    for(int i = k; i <= s->capacity-1; i++)
        printf("   '%s'\n", s->storage[i]);
    printf("}\n");
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "stack.h"

#define COM1    "echo"
#define COM2    "start"
#define COM3    "sort"

int main(){
    Stack *s = salloc(5);
    spush(s, COM1);
    spush(s, COM2);
    spush(s, COM3);
    // speek(s);
    print_stack(s); //Full Stack
    spop(s);
    print_stack(s);
    spush(s, "cd");
    print_stack(s);
    empty(s);
    print_stack(s);
}
```

Comment: Assuming you fix the primary structure allocation, You need to explain to your rubber duck what you think is being accomplished with `(s->capacity / sizeof(char *)` as the *byte* count for your shrink api (hint: that calculation is nonsense). And in *both* the shrink and expansion apis, you need to think about why *not* adjusting the `capacity` member is ultimately doom. How does any later use of the stack object know its capacity has been expanded or contracted?

Answer (score 0):

```
Stack *salloc(size_t size){
    Stack *s = (Stack *)malloc(sizeof(s));
    s->storage = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * size);
    s->capacity = size;
    s->size = 0;
}
```

Your first `malloc` call only allocates enough space for a `Stack*`, not enough space for the actual `Stack` structure. You want:

```
    Stack *s = (Stack *)malloc(sizeof(*s));
```

or

```
    Stack *s = (Stack *)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues in your code:

1. `salloc` is missing `return s`.
2. `spop` does not return anything (except for the `NULL` case).
3. `salloc` is not allocating enough memory for a `Stack` object (`sizeof(s)` is the size of the pointer, not the `Stack` object).
4. In all the calls in the form:  `s->storage = realloc(...)` - the result from `realloc` (`void*`) should be cast to `char**`.
5. `expand_stack` is defined to return an `int` but nothing is actually returned. Should probably be changed to return `void`.
6. `shrink_stack` is not calculating the size properly. As a result in your case `realloc` can actually allocate a 0 size memory (**Note:**: this is a cause for an access violation exception in `print_stack` after calling `spop`). I suggest you use a debugger to catch this bug.

Comment: Thanks for the useful corrections. So, what is the correct way to resize the stack after an element has been pop out?

Comment: It depends on the use pattern. Not sure there's a need to shrink allocated memory at all. Also see the comment above by WhozCraig.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of problems here.  Both in design and in implementation, but all lessons worth learning.

Here are a summary of the changes:

- `salloc` - We should store the initial capacity.  `empty` was just freeing all storage which would make the stack unusable.  By storing initial capacity, `shrink_stack` can avoid shrinking below that.
- `expand_stack` - `capacity` must be modified after the expansion or we lose track of what the actual allocation is.  Also, we wouldn't be able to add beyond the initial capacity without running into problems.  Going by the `int` return, I suspect you intended to return the new capacity (which should be `size_t`.
- `shrink_stack` should not just keep dividing the capacity, or eventually we hit zero.  So using the `initial_capacity` we keep things no smaller than at the outset.  It also needs to only shrink if the size has dropped to the point where there is value doing so.
- `spush` - I don't know why you chose to allocate from the end of the storage but this fundamentally would break when the capacity increased and expansion occurred.  Much simpler to add according to size, and pop off from size back towards zero. Note that `const` is added or some compilers will complain about passing a non-const pointer to a string literal, which is dangerous.
- `spop` - As per `spush`, pop from `size - 1` back towards zero.  The other bug here was that the string is stored in a malloc'd buffer, so we should be freeing that, and that means we can't just return the pointer, but need the `spop` signature to provide a buffer and max size in which to put it.  Given that we are dealing with null terminated strings, this can be an `strncpy`.  Note that the return value is the passed address, or NULL if there is no element to pop.  There are other ways to perhaps handle this that help remove the risk of elem == NULL etc.
- `speek` - Again, just use `size - 1`
- `empty` - Uses `spop` to remove all elements without discarding the initial capacity storage.
- `print_stack` - From zero to size.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>


typedef struct Stack{   
    char **storage;     //Elements container;
    size_t capacity;    //Total amount of elements POSSIBLE in the stack;
    size_t size;        //Total amount of elements within the stack;
    size_t initial_capacity;
}Stack;

Stack *salloc(size_t size){
    Stack *s = (Stack *)malloc(sizeof(s));
    s->storage = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * size);
    s->capacity = s->initial_capacity = size;
    s->size = 0;
    return s;
}

static int expand_stack(Stack *s){
    
    s->storage = (char **)realloc(s->storage, (sizeof(char *) * s->capacity * 2));
    s->capacity = s->capacity * 2;
    return s->capacity;
}

static void shrink_stack(Stack *s){
    if (s->capacity > s->initial_capacity && s->size < s->capacity / 2) {
        s->storage = (char **)realloc(s->storage, (sizeof(char *) * (s->capacity / 2)));
        s->capacity = s->capacity / 2;
    }
}

void spush(Stack *s, char const * elem){

    if(s->size == s->capacity)
        expand_stack(s);

    size_t size = strlen(elem) + 1;
    s->storage[s->size] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    memcpy(s->storage[s->size], elem, size);
    s->size++;
}

char *spop(Stack *s, char * elem, size_t size){

    if(s->size == 0)
        return NULL;

    if (size > 0) {
        strncpy(elem, s->storage[s->size - 1], size);
    }
    free(s->storage[s->size - 1]);
    s->storage[s->size - 1] = NULL;
    s->size--;
    shrink_stack(s);
    return elem;
}

void speek(Stack *s){
    printf("'%s'\n", s->storage[s->size - 1]);
}

void empty(Stack *s){
    char notused;
    while (spop(s, &notused, 0) != NULL);
}

void print_stack(Stack *s){
    printf("[STACK] = {\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < s->size; i++)
        printf("   '%s'\n", s->storage[i]);
    printf("}\n");
}

#define COM1    "echo"
#define COM2    "start"
#define COM3    "sort"

int main(){
    
    Stack *s = salloc(5);

    spush(s, COM1);
    spush(s, COM2);
    spush(s, COM3);

    // speek(s);

    print_stack(s); //Full Stack

    char string[64];
    spop(s, string, sizeof(string)/sizeof(string[0]));

    print_stack(s);

    spush(s, "cd");

    print_stack(s);

    empty(s);

    print_stack(s);
}
```